# Kotlin extension clash

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-extension

If I have a jar, on the classpath, where I've created an extension function on say the String class for argument's sake and I have another jar with the same extension function on String, how will Kotlin resolve the two?

I presume if both functions are defined in the same packages then there will be a clash?

But if different packages, how I can distinguish the two extensions?

Answer (score 20):

Indeed, if they're in the same package, it won't compile. For the other scenario, let's say you have two files with two different packages, containing extension functions with the same signature:

First file:

```
package ext1

fun Int.print() = print(this)
```

Second file:

```
package ext2

fun Int.print() = print(this * 2)
```

And this file where you're trying to use it:

```
package main

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    42.print()
}
```

IntelliJ will actually give you an import dialog where you can choose which one you want to use:

[image]

You can import one of them like this:

```
import ext1.print
```

And if you need to use the other one as well, you can rename it with the `as` keyword. This keyword works for imports in general, classes with the same name, etc.

```
import ext2.print as print2
```

So this program compiles and prints `4284`:

```
package main

import ext1.print
import ext2.print as print2

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    42.print()
    42.print2()
}
```

As a quick note, the one you import with the `as` keyword will be slightly harder to use, as autocomplete doesn't seem to pick it up well, selecting the second option here just completes the call to `42.print()`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 5):

So since extension function in kotlin is just static function, other functions will be distinguish by import.

Also you can make alias for one of extension functions for more readability:

```
import by.bkug.extensions.helpers.extension
import by.bkug.extensions.extension as extension1

fun test() {
    myType().extension() // by.bkug.extensions.helpers.extension
    myType().extention1() // by.bkug.extensions.extension
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer